# Can a non-right triangle be solved with only two sides if it is inside a parallelogram?

Tags: geometry, triangles

In [this triangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kv9cy.png)

I am given 2 side lengths for one triangle and two side lengths for the parallelogram. I am asked to find the length of **m** (FE) and **n** (DE)

I am given the lenghts:

- **h** (AC) = 9
- **k** (AF) = 15
- **f** (AB) = 16

I don't see how to use Law of Sines because I don't have any angles and I don't see how to use Law of Cosines to solve triangle **ACF** because I am missing a side length.

Am I missing a concept or is this problem missing given information?

Comment: I think there needs to be more information to uniquely determine $m$ and $n$. I posted an explanation below. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Are you sure you need to find the values of each of $m$ and $n$ individually? You can find their ratio by similar triangles, though where $f$ comes into it is a mystery.

Comment: I fixed a couple of typos in my solution. Was anything unclear? Please let me know. I'll be happy to help.

Comment: Oh, it's pretty clear. Thanks. --...David, yes. The problem I was shown is asking for those, but either way, can we really find the ratios by similar triangles on this problem? I think the problem is still missing data. I think that to find the ratios that way, the FED triangle would need to have at least one side defined.

Comment: This question does have an answer I think. The idea is that after you introduce a variable, everything is expressible in terms of that variable. You can then apply the cosine/sine rule to any of the triangles in the figure to solve for that variable and obtain the result. Or if you have not used the similarity of the triangles, you can use that to solve for the variable.

Comment: You can find the ratio of $m$ to $n$ by using the fact that triangle $FAC$ is similar to triangle $FED$. You get that $\frac{m}{n}=\frac{15}{9}$.

Comment: @Grimp0w If you feel that there is a way to solve this problem, then you're welcome to post a solution. Alternatively, you could have a look at mine. I've posted a solution that shows that the given conditions do not provide enough information to find $m$ (or $n$). If it is in fact possible to find $m$, then that my solution has a mistake. Is there something about my solution that you don't think is correct? Let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there's enough information. Let's let

$$A=(0,0)$$

$$B=(16,0)$$

$$C=(9\cos\theta,9\sin\theta)\text{ for some }0<\theta<90^{\circ}$$

$$D=B+C=(16+9\cos\theta,9\sin\theta)$$

$$F=\left(\sqrt{15^2-9^2\sin^2\theta},9\sin\theta\right)$$

Then we have a parallelogram $ABDC$ with a point $F$ on $CD$, such that $|AC|=9$, $|AF|=15$, and $|AB|=16$. Our next step is to find $E$. We'll be done if we can show that $|AE|$ is a non-constant function of $\theta$.

$E$ is the intersection of the lines determined by segments $AF$ and $BD$. To find the coordinates of $E$, we'll first find the equations of these lines. Using the point-slope form, we have that the equation for the line determined by segment $AF$ is:

$$y=\frac{9\sin\theta}{\sqrt{15^2-9^2\sin^2\theta}}\cdot x$$

Using the point-slope form, we have that the equation for the line determined by segment $BD$ is:

$$y=\frac{9\sin\theta}{9\cos\theta}\cdot (x-16)$$

Hence we can find the $x$-coordinate of $E$ by solving

$$\frac{9\sin\theta}{\sqrt{15^2-9^2\sin^2\theta}}\cdot x=\frac{9\sin\theta}{9\cos\theta}\cdot (x-16)$$

This gives us that

$$x=\frac{16\cdot\sqrt{15^2-9^2\sin^2\theta}}{\sqrt{15^2-9^2\sin^2\theta}-9\cos\theta}$$

We can then plug this into the equation for the line determined by segment $AF$ to obtain that

$$y=\frac{16\cdot9\sin\theta}{\sqrt{15^2-9^2\sin^2\theta}-9\cos\theta}$$

Hence

$$E=\left(\frac{16\cdot\sqrt{15^2-9^2\sin^2\theta}}{\sqrt{15^2-9^2\sin^2\theta}-9\cos\theta},\frac{16\cdot9\sin\theta}{\sqrt{15^2-9^2\sin^2\theta}-9\cos\theta}\right)$$

It follows that

$$|AE|=\frac{16\cdot15}{\sqrt{15^2-9^2\sin^2\theta}-9\cos\theta}$$

Note that if $\theta=30^{\circ}$, then $|AE|\approx36.8$, but if $\theta=60^{\circ}$, then $|AE|\approx28.9$. So $|AE|$ is a non-constant function of $\theta$.

Finally, note that $m=|AE|-15$. So $m$ is a non-constant function of $\theta$. We need more information.

Comment: I see. I also thought there was not enough information, but I wasn't sure about it. Thanks for the details.

Comment: Can't you express both $m$ and $n$ in terms of $\theta$ and solve for $\theta$ by using that you know their quotient?

Comment: The formula for $m$ is a bit complicated, but we've shown that $m=15\cdot f(\theta)$, where $f$ is a non-constant function of $\theta$. If we try to find a formula for $n$, we're going to end up with $n=9\cdot f(\theta)$. So $\frac{m}{n}=\frac{15}{9}$, but this won't help us find $\theta$.

Comment: Here's how we know we can't solve for $\theta$: if it was possible to somehow solve for $\theta$, then what that would show is that there is only one value of $\theta$ for which the above choices of the points $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, $E$, $F$ satisfy the given conditions. But for $0<\theta<90^{\circ}$, the above choices of the points will satisfy the given conditions regardless of what $\theta$ is, as you can check.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can  certainly reconstruct the image by  leaning the parallelogram to different angles and sliding F to where it needs to be. In other words by adjusting $\angle CAB$ to different values.

The question is is there some reason that for all measures of $\angle CAB$ will the lines $FE$ And $ED$ should be the same for all such parallelograms.  Off hand there is no reason they should.

But the more we increase $\angle CAB$ the more point $F$ will move to the right.  And as $9 < 15$ there is some angle where $F$ will move so far to the right so as to superimpose itself on $D$.  As a result $E$ will superimpose on $D$.  Then $FE= ED =0$.

Therefore $FE$ and $DE$ are *not* constant and we don't have enough information.

Comment: Were we given that angle $CAB$ is acute?

Comment: "Were we given that angle CAB is acute? "  No.  Does that matter.

Comment: We were'nt given that $CAB$ is acute but if $CF = g < 16$ if it is acute  $CF= g=16$ if is right. and $CF=g > 16$ if it is obtuse.  The image can not be drawn unless it is acute.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to stack exchange. The answer will simply be that $m = 15$ and $n = 9$. Lets say you made a new point G opposite E then joined C to G and then G to E, you'd effectively end up with the same parallelogram as you have underneath.

Comment: Did you prove that $m=15$? If the diagram you draw has a lot of symmetry, then it will look as though $m=15$, but we would need to prove this.

Comment: Hi Yung. Thanks for the answer. I tried using Geogebra to intersect lines with the parallelogram and while the diagram I have shows that it's almost the same, when I intersect lines and measure, the measurements are different. If I use different measurements, the k line length changes, but so does the m line length which ends up being different. Is there a math logic behind that can show they would always be the same regardless of the angle the k line takes?

Answer (score 0):

Note that the triangles $AFC$ and $EFD$ are similar. Hence $\frac{n}{m}=\frac{9}{15}$.

Now let the angle at E in $EFD$ be $x$. Then the angle at $A$ in $AFC$ is also $x$ by similarity. Using the cosine rule you can now find the lenght of g as a function of $x$, i.e. $g(x)$. Then $l(x)=16-g(x)$.

We have $n=\frac{9}{15}m$, hence we can now find $n(x)$ using the cosine rule in $EFD$. This thus gives $m(x)=\frac{15}{9}n(x)$. Now look at triangle $ABE$. Note that we know all sides as a function of $x$ and know that its angle at $E$ is $x$. Hence we can solve for $x$ by applying the cosine rule.

I however suspect that the actual calculations will be very ugly, so there probably is another solution possible.